# How to to return a DataTable and an Integer from a method?

Tags: c#

What's the easiest way to return two variables from a method? I want to return a `DataTable` and an `Integer`.

```
Private SomeType someMethod()
{
   int x=0;
   Datatable y;
   //return x and y
}
```

Comment: "most efficient" is probably already a moot point when returning a `DataTable`...

Comment: In two separate functions? Or as a custom object?

Comment: i added an explanation

Comment: I think the OP meant "How to return multiple values from the function"

Comment: @user1590636: Edited your question(title+content), is that what you actually meant?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, thats what i mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately, "best" is subjective and depends on your scenario. We can present *options*, but "best" is local to you.

There are various ways of returning multiple values; `out` is very efficient, but not very flexible, and many people find it confusing (indeed, some would say it is an anti-pattern). But for example:

```
DataTable Foo(out int val) {
   ...
   val = something
   return dataTable;
}
```

Perhaps more convenient is to declare a return type that *encapsulates* the two values:

```
FooResult Foo() {
   ...
   return new FooResult { Table = dataTable, Value = val };
}
```

where `FooResult` is a class with 2 properties. This has the advantage that you can add more properties trivially, without changing the API.

Similarly, you could return a `Tuple<DataTable,int>` - but I advise against it as it expresses nothing about what each value represents. In a `Tuple<string,int,string>`, what is `Item1` ? how is it different to `Item3` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the "most efficient" part of your question since it's pointless. You can use one [`out`-paremeter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee332485.aspx) and a [return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx):

```
public DataTable GetData(out int integerVariable)
{
    // ...
    integerVariable = 4711;
    return table;
}
```

You could also create and return a custom type which includes both, the `DataTable` and the `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return an object that exposes two properties, one of them an integer, and the other a DataTable.

Comment: You can create a class with needed function. Then you create an instance of this class, call the function (it may even be in the constructor), function will save result into properties and return.