# How to return default value when value is null or empty

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

How can I make the below code return zero if the returned value is null or empty. Also how can I return only the first record on the data table

```
  private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            gridoutofstock.DataBind();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AhlhaGowConnString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                sda.Dispose();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Return `0`? Your function is defined to return a `DataTable` - you cannot return `0`. You should probably add more details or clarify your question.

Comment: here is my sql command it only retuns one value select sum(Quantity) from [dbo].Orderdetails so what to use insted of data table?

Comment: Please edit your question with details, don't add them as comments - those may get overlooked by readers.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking "why I'm using `DataTable` as return type when I need `int`" - which is somewhat hard to reason about... Maybe you are looking for [returning both DataTable and int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384823/how-to-to-return-a-datatable-and-an-integer-from-a-method)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar instead of the SqlDataAdapter, you are trying to retrive a single scalar value and not a DataSet.

Example :

```
static int GetOrderQuantity()
        {
            int quantity = 0;
            string sql = "select sum(Quantity) from [dbo].Orderdetails ";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    quantity = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Handle exception
                }
            }
            return quantity;
        }
```